# Is it possible to get meta data about an Azure CloudFile w/o getting the file itself?

Tags: c#, azure

I fear the answer is "No" but I hope I'm wrong.

I have a list of 5,000+ file names, and all I need is the length (size) of each file.  I can do this:

```
foreach (string image in imageList)
{
  CloudFile pictureFile = myCloudFileDirectory.GetFileReference($"{_path}/image");
  Long imageSize = pictureFile.Properties.Length;
  // other logic
}
```

The problem is that with 5,000+ files, this little `foreach` takes way way way too long.

I'm trying to figure out how I can just get the `.Properties` w/o having to fetch the entire CloudFile.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
var someList = myCloudFileDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectories().ToList()
```

That did the trick. Within `someList` I can find the properties, and the file length (size).